# Parse LocalDate to hashMap Token

Tags: java

I need help with parsing `LocalDate` to a `HashMap` Tokens.
`currentOrder.setOrderDate(currentTokens[12])`. The `orderDate` in an `Order` object was given a `LocalDate` type. The error was given:

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to LocalDate.
```

I need a way to parse it in.

```
    private void loadOrder(LocalDate date) throws OrderPersistenceException {
    String path = getFilePath(date);
    File f = new File(path);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    Scanner scanner = null;

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new OrderPersistenceException("");
    }
    String currentLine;
    String[] currentTokens;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
        currentTokens = currentLine.split(DELIMITER);
        HashMap<Long, Order> orders = new HashMap<>();
        Order currentOrder = new Order(Long.parseLong(currentTokens[0]));
        currentOrder.setCustomerName(currentTokens[1]);
        currentOrder.setState(currentTokens[2]);
        currentOrder.setTaxRate(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[3]));
        currentOrder.setProductType(currentTokens[4]);
        currentOrder.setArea(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[5]));
        currentOrder.setCostPerSquareFoot(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[6]));
        currentOrder.setLaborCostPerSquareFoot(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[7]));
        currentOrder.setMeterialCost(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[8]));
        currentOrder.setLaborCost(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[9]));
        currentOrder.setTotalTax(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[10]));
        currentOrder.setTotal(new BigDecimal(currentTokens[11]));
        currentOrder.setOrderDate(currentTokens[12]);
        orders.put(currentOrder.getOrderNumber(), currentOrder);

        if (!orderMap.containsKey(currentOrder.getOrderDate())) {
            orderMap.put(currentOrder.getOrderDate(), orders);
        } else {
            orderMap.get(currentOrder.getOrderDate()).put(currentOrder.getOrderNumber(), currentOrder);

        }
    }
    scanner.close();

}
```

Order object;

```
public class Order {

    private Long orderNumber;
    private String customerName;
    private String state;
    private BigDecimal taxRate;
    private String productType;
    private BigDecimal area;
    private BigDecimal costPerSquareFoot;
    private BigDecimal laborCostPerSquareFoot;
    private BigDecimal meterialCost;
    private BigDecimal laborCost;
    private BigDecimal totalTax;
    private BigDecimal total;
    private LocalDate orderDate;




public Order(){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pulling a string from a file and attempting to add it to a LocalDate.  Per the following java doc you should use the parse method to parse the String date to a LocalDate object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-

```
    String myDate = "2007-12-03";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(myDate, formatter);
```

Comment: No need for the `formatter` object. That input’s standard ISO 8601 format is supported by default in the java.time classes. `LocalDate.parse( “2017-12-03” )`